# MSSQL 2017 on linux: Windows Authentication broken on CU14

Tags: sql-server, linux, kerberos

I am upgraded my mssql server on linux from CU12 to CU14, and that broke my windows authorization. 
Now when connecting, i'm getting error:

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18452)

If i'm trying to create a Windows user, i'm getting error:

> Error 15401: Windows NT user or group ‘username’ not found. Check the name again.

From shell, if i put:

```
id username
```

I'm getting normal response, either `kinit username` and then `klist` works well.

I noticed, in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-2017) that i could try to make direct connection to DC from krb5.conf:

```
sudo mssql-conf set network.disablesssd true
sudo mssql-conf set network.enablekdcfromkrb5conf true
systemctl restart mssql-server
```

however, it doesn't solve the problem.

SQL Server is set up under OpenSuse Leap 42.3

Error log of sql server contains only error about untrusted domain.